# Django ORM: checking if a field is blank or filled

Tags: django, django-orm

```
title = models.ForeignKey(blank=True, null=True)
```

I am trying to check if title filed is filled or blank, how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check is a field is blank or not by `isnull`

```
YourModel.objects.filter(title__isnull=True)
```

This will return all the objects which have no title.

Answer (score 3):

So for this, the Django docs around [querysets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#filter) and [q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) will be your friend.

Checking if something is `null` or `''` (empty) is a little tricky at first but once you understand SQL and Django ORM it will get easier.

The first point to make is `null != ''` in SQL they are two different values. The two previous answers to this post are incorrect as they did not read your question.

Basically there are three checks you could be performing depending on use case,

1. Is a result empty - `YourModel.objects.filter(title='')`
2. Is a result null - `YourModel.objects.filter(title__isnull=True)`
3. Is a result null or empty (using [Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)) - `YourModel.objects.filter(Q(title='') | Q(title__isnull=True))`

In your case, you will want option 3 as you are asking for a result set which shows null and empty values in a result set.

Example:

```
#  models.py
class TestModel(models.Model):
    a = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)

#  code
TestModel.objects.create() # id: 0
TestModel.objects.create(a='') # id: 1
TestModel.objects.create(a='a value') # id: 2

# option 1 above
TestModel.objects.filter(a__isnull=True)
#> <QuerySet [<TestModel: TestModel object (1)>]>

#option 2 above
TestModel.objects.filter(a='')
#> <QuerySet [<TestModel: TestModel object (2)>]>

#option 3 above
from django.db.models import Q
TestModel.objects.filter(Q(a='') | Q(a__isnull=True))
#> <QuerySet [<TestModel: TestModel object (1)>, <TestModel: TestModel object (2)>]>
```

Answer (score -1):

> I am trying to check if title filed is filled or blank, how can i achieve this?

`blank` is *not* a value. Blank means the field is not required in a form (it will not show up). Usually if `blank=True`, then `null=True` as well (or you need to provide an explicit default).

You can use `None` which is Python's equivalent of `NULL`, like:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(title=None)
```

or you can make it more explicit by using the [**`__isnull`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#isnull) lookup:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(title__isnull=True)
```